# Adding Hash parameter in the URL Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How to add a hash parameter in link_to. I need to generate a URL something like this..

```
/p/generate/#sometext
```

This is how my code looks now.

```
link_to "Click",my_path
```

How to add the hash parameter to my routes method.

**Now for the answer**

When I posted the question, I didn't got through the url helpers API fully. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

I did now. :) .I found the answer.

```
link_to "Click", my_path(:anchor => "sometext")
```

M.cypher below almost got it. :)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This is how you would usually do it:

```rb
link_to 'Click', my_path(anchor: 'sometext')
```

Your routes don't have much to do with it, since the anchor part (`#something`) is not transferred to the server, it's a pure client-side thing.

Comment: I agree that the hash parameter need not be sent to the server..But the :anchor symbol should be inside the routes method

Comment: If you also want the trailing slash, `/my_path/#sometext` rather than `/my_path#sometext` you also need to add `trailing_slash: true`, but most people should be fine with the current answer.

Answer (score 15):

I recognize this is an old post, but I thought I would contribute my recent discovery:

```
<%= link_to "New Person", polymorphic_path([:new, person], anchor: "profile") %>
```

See the [API Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url) for details.

Comment: Good find.  This is pretty much the most clear way to set params in a nested route helper imho.

Comment: that seem to make /stuff/preson/id#profile
How about getting /stuff/preson/id/#profile ?

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me a lot. :)